# How to exclude a folder from build on Docusaurus?

Tags: javascript, docusaurus

I am using Docusasurus for documenting the APIs. There is a subfolder created to store the development-related files that should not be part of `Docusasurus build`. I disabled it from the sidebar but I can access it using the full URL.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@docusaurus/core": "2.0.0-alpha.66",
    "@docusaurus/preset-classic": "2.0.0-alpha.66",
    "react": "^16.8.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.4",
    "swagger-ui-react": "^3.49.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "docusaurus start",
    "build": "docusaurus build",
  },  
  "resolutions": {
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "2.3.3"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exclude` field of `plugin-content-pages`. Check in [documentation](https://docusaurus.io/docs/2.0.1/api/plugins/@docusaurus/plugin-content-pages#exclude). Based on environment (dev or prod) you can fill this `exclude` field.

For example: `exclude: env == 'prod' ? [/path_to_your_subfolder/] : []`.

This will exclude url from production build but it will be available for dev environment.